# which selector to make navigation bar fixed and scroll with the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

heres the site
http://designobvio.us/DoUs/directPro.html

anyone know which selector I'd target to make my navigation bar scroll.

when i've tried it fixed broke my grid, If you could please give me a css snippet with the correct selector(s) i'd be very thankful!

```
<nav id="nav" class="grid_2">
  <ul>
   <a href="#"> <li><span>↗</span>Portfolio </li></a>
   <a href="#"> <li>Blog</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>About Me</li></a>
    <ul class="secondaryUL">
    <a href="#"><li>business</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>skills</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>service</li></a>
 <a href="#"><li>me</li></a>
   <a href="#"><li>contact</li></a>
  </ul>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Matthew

Comment: This is why I hate grid layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use CSS:

```
#nav{
    position: fixed;
}
```

Then you'll need to rely on a javascript fix to force a variable `margin-top` on `#id`.

Comment: thanks for the keywords for javascript fix.  Position:fixed is just too volitile.  it breaks the rest of the code...

Answer (score 1):

First thing First, i think u mst layout correctly i.e

```
<nav id="nav" class="grid_2">    
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>↗</span>Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    <li>
        <ul class="secondaryUL">
           <li><a href="#">business</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">skills</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">service</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
 </ul>    
</nav>
```

After then u can fixed the position of `nav#id` i.e
    #nav{float:left;position:fixed}